# How to override titlewindow 4px padding in flex actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, border, padding

I am new to flex and i am trying to create a title window with no padding whatsoever on the sides. In the adobe documentation http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/TitleWindow.html it says that the title window has a 4px padding. I was wondering if i could get rid of it by overriding the updateDisplayList function and set the padding to 0 (I have been trying this but I cant seem to find the right attribute to set). Basically what i want to do is to have a button on the bottom left corner of the title window and the edge of the button should be 0px from the border of the window.

PS: I only need to do this for title window. There is probably another way of doing it with a Panel or some other component which im not interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link to the `TitleWindow` docs has a [styles](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/TitleWindow.html#styleSummary) section. It has styles for `paddingTop`, `paddingBottom`, `paddingLeft`, and `paddingRight`.

CSS styles are set a little differently in Actionscript versus MXML. Since css styles are not properties of the object, you have to use the `setStyle()` method in Actionscript. You can also use a style sheet.

MXML:

```
<mx:TitleWindow paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" />
```

Actionscript:

```
var tw:TitleWindow = new TitleWindow();
tw.setStyle("paddingLeft", 0);
tw.setStyle("paddingRight", 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not work. If i do this <mx:TitleWindow layout="vertical"    
 verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" 
 initialize="loadPage()" 
 paddingLeft="0"  paddingBottom="0" paddingRight="0" paddingTop="0">

I still see the 4px on each side of the TitleWindow, even if i set the style of the paddings to 0 it will still show the 4 px paddings.  I guess that is the default value for the title window. That is why i was thinking of overriding how the Titlewindow is constructed. I just cannot figure out how to set the padding to 0. Thanks again

Comment: Padding controlls the space between the inside edge of the TitleWindow and it's contents. Set one of the padding values really large and you will see what it does. There is also a 5px border around the TitleWindow - this is part of the "chrome" around the window. Perhaps you want to change that? A screen shot of what you want to change might confirm this. (BTW, there is a `borderThickness` style, but that doesn't seem to effect the chrome around the window, however changing `borderColor` does.

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/86824822@N02/7951063584/in/photostream.  So pretty much i want to remove the "chrome" around the window. I want it to look like the right side of that login form.

Comment: Your link to the TitleWindow documentation is for `<mx:TitleWindow/>` so I assumed Flex 3, but your screenshot looks like Flex 4. With the Spark TitleWindow you should be able to make your own skin. Can you confirm version of Flex you are using?

Comment: Hey I'm sorry i misguided you with the screenshot. I am actually using Flex 3 and that screenshot was taken from adobe site just to show the idea of what i am trying to do.

Comment: No worries. Earlier I tried `borderThickness` style (which did nothing), but in looking at code noticed that it uses `borderThicknessLeft` and `borderThicknessRight`. That and the padding styles should do what you are after, I hope :)

Comment: Great!!! that actually worked. I didnt know that those 4-5px were part of the border. Thanks a lot, saved me a lot of time :)